# A better way to find out how many bytes are in a stream?

Tags: java, apache, stream, streaming

Currently, I am relying on the `ObjectInputStream.available()` method to tell me how many bytes are left in a stream. Reason for this -- I am writing some unit/integration tests on certain functions that deal with streams and I am just trying to ensure that the `available()` method returns 0 after I am done.

Unfortunately, upon testing for failure (i.e., I have sent about 8 bytes down the stream) my assertion for `available() == 0` is coming up true when it should be false. It should show >0 or 8 bytes!

I know that the `available()` method is classically unreliable, but I figured it would show something at least > 0!

**Is there a more reliable way of checking if a stream is empty or not (The is my main goal here after all)?** Perhaps in the Apache IO domain or some other library out there?

Does anyone know why the `available()` method is so profoundly unreliable; what is the point of it? Or, is there a specific, proper way of using it?

---

**Update:**

So, as many of you can read from the comments, the main issue I am facing is that on one end of a stream, I am sending a certain number of bytes but on the other end, not all the bytes are arriving!

Specifically, I am sending 205498 bytes on one end and only getting 204988 on the other, consistently. I am controlling both sides of this operation between threads in a socket, but it should be no matter.

Here is the code I have written to collect all the bytes.

```
  public static int copyStream(InputStream readFrom, OutputStream writeTo, int bytesToRead)
      throws IOException {

    int bytesReadTotal = 0, bytesRead = 0, countTries = 0, available = 0, bufferSize = 1024 * 4;

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    while (bytesReadTotal < bytesToRead) {

      if (bytesToRead - bytesReadTotal < bufferSize)
        buffer = new byte[bytesToRead - bytesReadTotal];

      if (0 < (available = readFrom.available())) {
        bytesReadTotal += (bytesRead = readFrom.read(buffer));
        writeTo.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        countTries = 0;

      } else if (countTries < 1000)
        try {
          countTries++;
          Thread.sleep(1L);

        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
      else

        break;
    }

    return bytesReadTotal;
  }
```

I put the countTries variable in there just to see what happens. Even without countTires in there, it will block forever before it reaches the BytesToRead.

**What would cause the stream to suddenly block indefinitely like that?** I know on the other end it fully sends the bytes over (as it actually utilizes the same method and I see that it completes the function with the full BytesToRead matching bytesReadTotal in the end. But the receiver doesn't. In fact, when I look at the arrays, they match up perfectly up till the end as well.

**UPDATE2**

I noticed that when I added a `writeTo.flush()` at the end of my copyStream method, it seems to work again. Hmm.. Why are flushes so vital in this situation. I.e., why would not using it cause a stream to perma-block?

Comment: How are you supposed to know there are `x` bytes in a stream without reading it? The `available()` method clearly states _Returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking._ If you were to read more bytes, you would need to block.

Comment: You should check with `InputStream#read()` returning `-1` to see if the end of the stream has been reached.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, shouldn't `available()` give at least a return value of 1 to show that there is at least 1 byte to read while blocking?

Comment: If it could read 1 byte without blocking, it would say so. **It can't know how many bytes it can read while blocking without having read them (ie. reach end of stream).**

Comment: I see... well this is interesting. In the case where I am expecting nothing left in the stream, I am actually reading one byte 0x79 and after that, the `.read()` method blocks indefinitely... Do these symptoms remind you of anything?

Comment: I am thinking I Need to do some kind of a reset or flush on the respective outputstream so the input stream on the other side knows not to block.

Comment: It blocks until there is data to read or the peer *closes* his socket. You need to understand that the total number of bytes in a stream is undefined. The sender could keep sending data forever.

Comment: @EJP Thanks I understand this now. So the mystery is: How come I know I am sending 2005498 bytes at one end but only recieving 2004988. After 204988 it completely blocks and says `.available() == 0`

Answer (score 2):

The `available()` method only returns how many bytes can be read **without blocking** (which may be 0).  In order to see if there are any bytes left in the stream, you have to `read()` or `read(byte[])` which will return the number of bytes read. If the return value is `-1` then you have reached the end of file.

This little code snippet will loop through an InputStream until it gets to the end (read() returns -1).  I don't think it can ever return 0 because it should block until it can either read 1 byte or discover there is nothing left to read (and therefore return -1)

```
int currentBytesRead=0;
int totalBytesRead=0;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

while((currentBytesRead =in.read(buf))>0){
        totalBytesRead+=currentBytesRead;

}
```

Comment: Currently I'm using something like this:

    int b;
    while ((b = singleServersT.getInputStream().read()) != -1) {
      System.err.print(b);
    }

But its actually blocking after the first byte read! I added comments to my original post about this new light.

Comment: Yeah, your code does the same. TotalBytesRead == 1 after the first loop, after that it blocks.

Comment: it's supposed to block, you can't tell how many bytes are left in the entire stream without blocking.

Comment: Hmm, how can you then force send an EOF?

Comment: For testing you can either mock the InputStream or return an instance that wraps a byte[] like  new ByteArrayInputStream(myBytes); which will send EOF after all the bytes in the array have been read.  As a bonus since the array is all in memory, it won't block either so available() will return the length of the array

Comment: that sounds like a great idea but won't work in this instance because the testing includes creation of real sockets.

Comment: @EricS you send an EOS by closing the socket, or shutting it down for output.

Comment: @EJP The problem is I need to keep reading from the stream. I.e., as the program progresses, the In and Out stream keep interacting with each other so I don't want to fully close the stream. I just want each read<>() operation to finish without blocking.

Comment: @EricS So use non-blocking mode, or superimpose a protocol that tells you when each message has finished, such as a length-word prefix, XML, serialization, type-length-value, ... TCP doesn't do that. It's a byte stream.